# Operation conditional on time index for longitudinal data in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have some data organized in the longitudinal format, i.e.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
time=rep(c(1990, 1995, 2000,2005), 4)
w = runif(16, min=0, max=1)
u = runif(16, min=0, max=0.5)
dat <- cbind(id,time,w,u)
dat
id time         w         u
1 1990 0.6550168 0.2114829
1 1995 0.9669285 0.2253474
1 2000 0.8879138 0.2733263
1 2005 0.1079913 0.4452164
2 1990 0.1483843 0.1949214
2 1995 0.7599596 0.1632965
2 2000 0.7119100 0.3600129
2 2005 0.4164409 0.2456366
3 1990 0.7881798 0.3233312
3 1995 0.8627986 0.1180433
3 2000 0.3253139 0.3491878
3 2005 0.2560138 0.3193816
4 1990 0.2062351 0.3485047
4 1995 0.4145230 0.1413814
4 2000 0.3053510 0.1782681
4 2005 0.7419894 0.3738163
```

I need to compute `B` as follows

[image: B]

where t and s refers to time. I tried for a loop using two indexes  `i` and `j`but I got no output. Then i tried differently, such as

```
B.small = list()
for (r in c(1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010)){
     B.small = (set$w[set$year ==r, ]%*% t(set$w)%*%set$u[set$year ==r, ]*set$u)/n
}
B = sum(B.Small)/n

Error in set$u[set$year == r, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

`B`must be a scalar. I guess there must be an alternative, also without using a loop

Comment: What's `E` in your formula?

Comment: Expected value. Therefore, the result in [] should be divided by n

Comment: You already divide by `n` outside the sum. Is there another `1/n` factor?

Comment: Looks like that. An expected value corresponds to a mean, therefore it should be divided by the number of observations, `n`. I took that directly from the authors text. To be precise they write that B tends in probability to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your formula enough and for sure there could be a better way to do it, but I'd try:

```
    #split the matrix by year
    splitDT<-split(as.data.frame(dat[,3:4]),dat[,2])
    #build any combinations of indices of year
    indices<-expand.grid(1:length(splitDT),1:length(splitDT))
    #evaluate the mean of each combination and put in a matrix
    res<-matrix(mapply(function(x,y) mean(splitDT[[x]]$u*splitDT[[y]]$u*splitDT[[x]]$w*splitDT[[y]]$w),
                       indices[,1],indices[,2]),
                ncol=length(splitDT))
    #get the result
    sum(res)/ncol(res)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your effort. Secondly, may you explain me the function applied to res ? looks to me you are just multiplying `w*u`, when it should be `w*t(w)*u*u`. In my case, w is a column, so it is just `w*w*u*u`. About my formula, forget the E[ ] and just consider [ ]/n.

Comment: Ops, you are right, I did an edit. Now it multiplies `w*w*u*u` as written in the formula.

Comment: Last question: I get `res` as a `txt`matrix. I am not able to figure out what that object should look like, but i guess it follows the dimension of `t`. Is that right?

Comment: The number of rows and columns should match the number of different values of `time`, if I got your formula.

Comment: yes, `t`and `s`refer to time. I will give it a try and I will report you back Thank you

Comment: Now I see what the problem may be. Since I was referring to `n` as the number of observations in the panel (`id`), while it looks like the `(1/n)`outside the double sum refers to `t`and `s` . I will check the details about that. EDIT: authors are mixing indices for time and id in the equation, while before they were using `t` and `s` for time, and `i = 1... n` for observations. However, the problem with the error term `u` is serial correlation. Therefore I guess that `n`stands for time. If interested, the reference is Racin and Li (2007)'s book, p.507, eq (16.5). Thanks again.